# Inner loop constructors not eliminated by GHC

Tags: haskell, optimization, stream, ghc

I am trying to, roughly, play with different stream fusion approaches to the code

```
sum (filter even [0..n])
```

and have reached a point where I would expect constructor specialization to kick in (with `-O2`, etc), but it doesn't seem to be kicking in.

With `-ddump-simpl`, I get the following Core:

```
Rec {
-- RHS size: {terms: 33, types: 10, coercions: 0}
Main.main_go [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: Int -> RangeToState -> Int
[GblId, Arity=2, Caf=NoCafRefs, Str=DmdType]
Main.main_go =
  \ (z_a1Nf :: Int) (s1_a1Ng :: RangeToState) ->
    case s1_a1Ng of _ [Occ=Dead] { RangeToState ipv_s7O5 ipv1_s7O6 ->
    case z_a1Nf of z1_X1NN { GHC.Types.I# ipv2_s7O9 ->
    case GHC.Prim.tagToEnum# @ Bool (GHC.Prim.<# ipv_s7O5 ipv1_s7O6)
    of _ [Occ=Dead] {
      False -> z1_X1NN;
      True ->
        Main.main_go
          (case GHC.Prim.remInt# ipv_s7O5 2# of _ [Occ=Dead] {
             __DEFAULT -> z1_X1NN;
             0# -> GHC.Types.I# (GHC.Prim.+# ipv2_s7O9 ipv_s7O5)
           })
          (Producer.RangeToState (GHC.Prim.+# ipv_s7O5 1#) ipv1_s7O6)
    }
    }
    }
end Rec }
```

(with `data RangeToState = RangeToState {-# UNPACK #-} !Int {-# UNPACK #-} !Int`.)

I would have expected `RangeToState` and `I#` to get eliminated, and when I manually translate the Core from above back into basic Haskell:

```
foo2 = \ (z :: Int) (s :: RangeToState) ->
    case s of 
      RangeToState i n -> z `seq` case i < n of
        False -> z
        True -> foo2 (if even i then i + z else z)
          (RangeToState (i+1) n)
```

it does indeed get compiled down to an allocationless loop:

```
Rec {
-- RHS size: {terms: 31, types: 6, coercions: 0}
Producer.$wfoo2 [InlPrag=[0], Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int#
[GblId, Arity=3, Caf=NoCafRefs, Str=DmdType <L,U><S,U><S,U>]
Producer.$wfoo2 =
  \ (ww_s4gO :: GHC.Prim.Int#)
    (ww1_s4gS :: GHC.Prim.Int#)
    (ww2_s4gT :: GHC.Prim.Int#) ->
    case GHC.Prim.tagToEnum# @ Bool (GHC.Prim.<# ww1_s4gS ww2_s4gT)
    of _ [Occ=Dead] {
      False -> ww_s4gO;
      True ->
        case GHC.Prim.remInt# ww1_s4gS 2# of _ [Occ=Dead] {
          __DEFAULT ->
            Producer.$wfoo2 ww_s4gO (GHC.Prim.+# ww1_s4gS 1#) ww2_s4gT;
          0# ->
            Producer.$wfoo2
              (GHC.Prim.+# ww1_s4gS ww_s4gO) (GHC.Prim.+# ww1_s4gS 1#) ww2_s4gT
        }
    }
end Rec }
```

My compilation options are just `ghc -O2 -fforce-recomp -ddump-simpl`, and I'm using GHC 8.0.2.

What is stopping the first version of the code from getting further compiled down to the second version?

Comment: You can run `-dverbose-core2core` and see what the code looks like before the strictness analyzer, which does the kind of unboxing you want. Maybe it is not yet in the shape at that point?

Comment: Can you show your actual source code? How are you defining and rewriting `sum`, `enumFromTo`, and `filter`? Without that info, it's going to be pretty much impossible to produce a proper answer to this question.

Comment: Have you figured out the problem? If so, please answer this question. If not, I'd appreciate if you'd refine it as I asked. I find these sorts of puzzles fun, but I can't approach this one without all the pieces.

Comment: I have not figured out the problem, but will update the question as soon as I can extract a useful subset of the code.

Comment: Any update? Have GHC's developments with join points made this better (or worse)?